# Delphi dbgrid with wildcard character

Tags: delphi

I have DBGrid. Sometimes, if i change some cell value, it give a wildcard. You can see that in the image.

[image: img]

My question : when this wildcard, it can be appear? How can disable that?

Comment: That asterisk (*) indicates that the dataset connected to the DBGrid is in `dsInsert` state, i.e. it has begun to add a record but has not yet posted it.

Comment: Btw, you can hide the LH, gray column the asterisk appears in by setting `dgIndicator` to False in the grid's `Options` property in the OI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` is an indicator that your dbgrid is in insert mode.

If you don't want this indicator to appear you can change (the drawing of) it in the [`OnDrawColumnCell`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.OnDrawColumnCell) event.
If you use this event you may need to set `dbGrid.DefaultDrawing` to false.

See also: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Controlling_Grid_Drawing

Another option is to implement your own custom style.

```
type
  TMyStyleWithNoIndicator = class(TCustomStyleServices)
    function GetElementDetails(Detail: TThemedGrid): TThemedElementDetails; override;  
  end;

  function TMyStyleWithNoIndicator.GetElementDetails(Detail: TThemedGrid): TThemedElementDetails; 
  begin
    inherited;
    //prevent drawing of the insert indicator.
    if Detail in [tgIndicatorInsert] then Result.State = Ord(tgCellNormal);
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Form1Create(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    TStyleManager.SetStyle(TMyStyleWithNoIndicator.Create);
  end;
```